# How to integrate test-cases specified by external files into `cargo test`

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

Within Rusts build-tool `cargo`, I can define a function for a test-case simply this way:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_something() {
    assert_eq!(true, true);
}
```

Running with `cargo test` outputs:

```
Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/example-14178b7a1a1c9c8c)

running 1 test
test test::test_something ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

So far, so good. Now I have the special case, that test cases in my project are defined in files. They can be executed using a special `testcase()` function that performs all steps to run the test, and do specific `assert_eq!()` calls.

Now I want to achieve the following:

1. Read all files from a `tests/` folder
2. Run `testcase()` on every file
3. Have every file as a single test case in `cargo test`

Latter one is the problem. This is the function (as test) to run all tests from the folder using the `testcase()`-function.

```rust
#[test]
// Run all tests in the tests/-folder
fn tests() {
    let cases = std::fs::read_dir("tests").unwrap();

    for case in cases {
        testcase(case.unwrap().path().to_str().unwrap());
    }
}
```

A run of `cargo test` should print the following, given the testcases `a.test`, `b.test` and `c.test`:

```
Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/example-14178b7a1a1c9c8c)

running 3 test
test test::tests::tests/a.test ... ok
test test::tests::tests/b.test ... ok
test test::tests::tests/c.test ... ok

test result: ok. 3 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: "that test cases in my project are defined in files." - What kind of files?

Comment: The project I'm on is a programming language. A test-case file defines a program and a desired output to stdout and stderr, written as comment. This is easier than doing a specific assert_eq!() all the time with an compiler/vm run and output value object construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Rust's built-in test harness, there is **no** way to declare a single test case other than with the `#[test]` attribute. In order to get the result you want, you would need to write a proc-macro which reads your directory of tests and generates a `#[test]` function for each one.

Instead, it will probably be more practical to write a test which uses your own harness code. In your `Cargo.toml`, define a test target with it disabled:

```rust
[[test]]
name = "lang_tests"
harness = false
```

Then in `tests/lang_tests.rs` (the `tests/` directory goes next to `src/` and [is already known to Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html)), write a program with an ordinary `main()` that runs tests:

```rust
fn main() {
    let cases = std::fs::read_dir("tests").unwrap();

    let mut passed = 0;
    let mut failed = 0;
    for case in cases {
        if testcase(case.unwrap().path().to_str().unwrap()) {
            eprintln!("...");
            passed += 1;
        } else {
            eprintln!("...");
            failed += 1;
        }
    }

    eprintln!("{passed} passed, {failed} failed");
    if failed > 0 {
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

Of course there's a bunch of further details to implement here — but I hope this illustrates how to write a custom test harness that does the thing you want to do. Again, you cannot do it with the default test harness except by using macro-generated code, which is probably not worthwhile in this case.

Comment: Hello Kevin! Thanks for the clarification. Writing a proc-macro on this was also a thought I had when writing this issue. I've already started a separate crate that provides tools as proc-macro for built-in functions, maybe I can add the test-case based on files there, too. Anyway, thank you for providing a useful example code. This shows up different and new perspectives on the problem.